# How to trigger number displayed at the bottom of the table of DataTable plugin in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am just querious to know how to trigger the page number displayed at the bottom of the table of DataTable() function in jquery. I searched lot in google but I didn't get even single solution or idea. I am ready to accept any solutions and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear on exactly what you are looking for...

#### To use the DataTables API to get page information

```
var dt = $("#myTable").DataTable({...});

var total_pages = dt.page.info().pages;
var current_page = dt.page.info().page;
```

API Reference: [**page.info()**](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.info())

#### To set the Page Information Configuration

```
var dt = $("#myTable").DataTable({
    dom: "lfrtip" // i = info, indicates DOM order
    paging: false // to turn off default is true
});
```

Option Reference: [**paging**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/paging)

Option Reference: [**dom**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom)

To customize text: [**language.paginate**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.paginate)